# Eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win 32 Not Launching

Tags: java, eclipse

1.I'm a new Android developer, still learning Java, who has installed the Eclipse-java-helios-SR-win 32 on my desktop.

2.I have installed the new Java SE 6 and the Android SDK. I use Win 7.

3.When I try to launch the Eclipse application I get the below error

A Java Runtime Enviroment(JRE) or Java Developmet Kit(JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse.No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
C\:Users\User\Desktop\eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe in your current PATH.

4.However I have already created this PATH in my System Variables!

Comment: Can you open a cmd window and post the output of `echo %PATH%`

Comment: The output is                              \Users\Users\Desktop\eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\jre\bin

Comment: Hey Jon, is that an appropriate place for Eclipse? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jon,to a large extent you right that the Eclipse and Android SDK issues had to do with the path.See the comments with Isaac below for the full solution and thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `PATH` environment variable seems to contain the actual `javaw.exe` executable. That won't work. Remove the suffix `\javaw.exe` from the `PATH`.
2. Not sure about Windows 7, but at least in Windows XP, after you change environment variables, you have to close & re-open your command-prompt window for the change to take effect (changes to environment variables aren't propagated to existing, running processes).

Comment: Thanks Isaac.I tried it out...it didn't workout...any other suggestions?

Comment: It seems a bit weird that it's looking for a JRE inside Eclipse's installation folder. Eclipse itself never ships with a JRE. Did you by chance extract or install a JRE into `eclipse/jre`?

Comment: 1.No I didn't extract or install a JRE into eclipse.I assume that Eclipse once extracted should automatically use Java which I had earlier installed where it will find the JRE to use.                                               2.Am I right or do I need to extract the eclipse to a specific destination for it to use the JRE in the installed Java program?

Comment: If you open a command-prompt window and type `java -version`, do you get any output? Also, when installing Java, did you install the JRE or the JDK (or both)?

Comment: I installed both the JRE and JDK. The output when I type     User>Users> java -version is                                      'java' is not a recognized internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: So that's the problem. The JDK & JRE you installed didn't add themselves to the PATH. I only seen this before when installing the 64-bit edition of Java; are you using the 64-bit edition of Java?

Comment: No I installed the 32-bit edition but I just noticed that its command window and that of my Android SDK are not functioning.Maybe I need to re-install the Java?

Comment: I never worked with Android SDK before, and I don't think it's related; if you installed a JRE on Windows and it didn't add itself to the system's PATH, then something is screwy. Either reinstall the JRE or edit your system's PATH to include the JRE's "bin" directory.

Comment: Hi Isaac,I re-installed everything again,please see below

Comment: I had to cut and paste all the Eclipse files and put them inside the Java Program Files.From there I could launch Eclipse.

Comment: Hey Isaac,I'd like to add that for the Android SDK to work I had to install windows XP and create the path for the Android SDK where it is located in Java(JRE) in the bin directory.So you were a right!Thank you.